# Showing that a function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free abelian group.

Show that $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \times F / p F \rightarrow F/pF: (a,v) \mapsto av$, where $av=(c+p\Bbb Z)(h+pF) = ch+pF$ is well defined.

I know this means to show that If $c+p\Bbb Z=c'+p\Bbb Z$ and $h+pF=h'+pF$, then $ch+pF = c'h'+pF$.  I can see that, assuming the two arguments are equal, $c'=c+pj$ for some $j \in \Bbb Z $ and $h'=h+pg$ for some $g \in F$, but from here I'm stuck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: We do not need $F$ to be free. For any abelian group the quotient $F/pF$ has a $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$-module structure.

Answer (score 0):

...  so $$ c'h'=(c+pj)(h+pg)=ch+pjh+p^2jg+cpg=ch+p\cdot(jh+pjg+cg)$$

Comment: So in a free abelian group, addition is distributive over the operation $mb$, where $m \in \Bbb Z$ and $b \in F$?